# Selecting <li> in groups of 3

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, grouping

I am trying to select `<li>` in groups of 3, currently I am using `:gt` and `:lt` like this

```
 $('.events_list li:lt(7):gt(3)').css('display', 'block');
```

This is ok but seems like there may be a better way. I just want to click a button and select the next 3 `<li>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var triplet = 0;

$('button').click(function(){
    $('.events_list li')
        .hide() // hide the ones that are visible
        .filter(function(i){
            return i >= triplet*3 && i < (triplet+1)*3; // filter the next 3
        })
        .show(); // and show them

    triplet++;
});
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/PyEhU/

Answer (score 0):

you can try also [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$('.events_list li:eq(3)').nextUntil('.events_list li:eq(7)').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("ul li").filter(function(index,el){return index>3 && index<7}).css('display', 'block');
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

[Gaby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725082/932484) worked well for me (and I would have upvoted it if I could), but *my* use case required a loop, and the one issue with $.filter is that it goes over all the elements in every loop pass. So I used [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) instead, which allows you to select elements out of a set. It also makes the code slightly simpler. As an added bonus, I moved the selector out of the function, as I assume the list itself does not change and therefore there's no need to select it again and again.

This is my version, based on Gaby's:

```
var triplet = 0;
var $elements = $('.events_list li');

$('button').click(function(){
    $elements
        .hide() // hide the ones that are visible
        .slice( triplet*3, (triplet+1)*3)
        .show(); // and show them

    triplet++;
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/sf3N9/